# Removing the first or last delimeter in a string SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
create table addresses (address varchar(50));
insert into addresses(address) values
('123 Pillage Road, EN45EX'),
('123 Pill,age Road, EN45EX'),
('123 Pillage Road, EN4,5EX');
```

and i'm trying to remove the first `,` delimiter and the last by:

```
update addresses 
set address = 
        case address
                when strpos(address, ',') < 17 then regexp_replace(address, ',','')
                when strpos(address, ',') > 17 then REVERSE(regexp_replace(REVERSE(address), ',',''))
        end
where char_length(address) - char_Length(replace(address,',','')) > 1
```

This gives a

```
ERROR:  operator does not exist: character varying = boolean
LINE 4:     when strpos(address, ',') < 17 then regexp_replace(addre...
            ^
```

So Im finding the middle delimiter location (17) and trying to do a specific replace function on the delimiters found before and after. Where is the error coming from?

Comment: `case x when 1 then y end` or `case when x = 1 then y end`, but not `case x when x = 1 then y end`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used positive look back `(?<=\w)` and positive look ahead `(?=\w)`. thus, if a comma is between two characters or numbers, then it is replaced with an empty space

```
select regexp_replace(address, '(?<=\w),(?=\w)', '', 'g') from addresses;
```

results

```
      regexp_replace
--------------------------
 123 Pillage Road, EN45EX
 123 Pillage Road, EN45EX
 123 Pillage Road, EN45EX
```

and query with update

```
update addresses set address=regexp_replace(address, '(?<=\w),(?=\w)', '', 'g');
```

Comment: Hi could you explain the verbal process in what you wrote, looks very interesting

Comment: @Jack Hi i have added an explanation

Comment: Thank you so much, Im guessing it didnt work because the middle delimiter had a space next to it. What if this wasnt the case

Comment: Then you would have to write a pattern suitable for the condition

Answer (score 1):

Remove the address identifier from `CASE`:

```
update addresses 
set address = 
        case 
                when strpos(address, ',') < 17 then regexp_replace(address, ',','')
                when strpos(address, ',') > 17 then REVERSE(regexp_replace(REVERSE(address), ',',''))
        end
where char_length(address) - char_Length(replace(address,',','')) > 1
```

Comment: Damn that is a painfully dumb mistake... Thanks though!